# How to load CSV file into mysql when value/text/field contains ',' using batch script

Tags: mysql, csv, batch-file

When I am loading CSV file into MySQLworkbench it is not displaying data as I need.

CSV file/Excelfile:

```
src_table      src_col         rule
employee        empno          replace(100,1001)
employee        empname        replace('c',s)
employee        country        replace('india','ind')
```

And I save the above Excel file as CSV (comma (`,`) seperated).

My batch file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\EQA\\project\\tablename.csv" INTO TABLE table_name CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Expected Output:

```
src_table      src_col         rule
employee        empno          replace(100,1001)
employee        empname        replace('c',s)
employee        country        replace('india','ind')
```

Actual Output:

```
src_table      src_col         rule
employee        empno          replace(100
employee        empname        replace('c'
employee        country        replace('india'
```

As you can see, the commas and everything after them are completely ignored!

Comment: You need to export your data from Excel with fields escaped by double quote.

Comment: When "saving as" in Excel, select a different delimiter - a character that you know will never appear in your data. For example, I use tab-delimited files as I know tabs will never appear in my data. Alternately, follow @TimBiegeleisen 's suggestion and wrap each field in double quotations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your database encoding to **UTF-8**  and also csv file encoding to **UTF-8** .

You can open your CSV file in Notepad++ and then you can see your files current encoding format. Then you have to change it UTF-8

Same for your database open database using DB browser and set UTF-8 as encoding.

This procedure may work. If still not work then comment on comment section please.

Comment: Thanks for u r response,But still i am unable to get accurate result @flopcoder